# Kafka Log file increasing continuously

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

My kafka server is running on my linux machine and approx 50 clients are connected and are working fine. Only one issue is there that the log file of some client is increasing even if no message in published by producer.
My consumer in initialized with two topics = "systemupdate" and "cfba196cfce64feeb5f414a85306f88e".

Screenshot is of log file is attached.

Please tell me if I am missing some thing in configuration

[Attached logs screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZ7J3.png)

thanks and Regards
Deepak Purbia